# Meaning of "a Richard Snary" / "a Given Name"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, formal-language, jokes, archaic-language

An old joke I found in Mark Forsyth's "The Etymologicon", originally mentioned in the OED

> A country lad, having been reproved for calling persons by their Christian names, being sent by his master to borrow a dictionary, thought to show his breeding by asking for **a** Richard Snary.

I understand the joke (for those who don't, the boy misheard *Dictionary* as *Dick Snary*, thinking it's a man's name.

Ignoring the outdated pronunciation needed for the joke to work, the confusion only works with "borrow **a** dictionary" and "borrow **a** Dick Snary"

It doesn't work in modern English, "get **a** dictionary" and "get Dick Snary" doesn't quite have the same effect.

But what does this old-fashioned article "**a**" before a person's name mean?

Comment: Nothing. Per the joke, the boy is simply repeating what he thought his master said.

Comment: this may be more of a question for "english language and usage"

Comment: One might ask "is there a Richard Snary in the house?"

Comment: In the UK, I don't know about elsewhere, you can use an indefinite article before a person's name to mean "a person named", especially if the person has not previously been mentioned or is unknown to the listener or reader.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  it works the same in the U.S.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-post of [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474029/meaning-of-a-richard-snary-a-given-name). Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: @Em. FYI we noticed at ELU also. Since this is the original Q, and the ELU Q was the later repost, we deleted ours.

Answer (score 2):

Your objection to the joke is valid in older or current English.  It would work fine if you phrased it as *borrowing* some person's *time*, as a polite way to ask for their help:

> The boy asked if his master could **borrow a** Mr. Richard Snary (for a short while).

The use of "a" before a person's name indicates that the boy knows the *name* of the person, but not *who* exactly is that person, or even if that person is actually there.  For example, suppose you call somewhere to ask for a particular person, but you're not sure if you have the right location:

> Receptionist: Hello, this is the White House.  How may I direct your call?
>
> You:  Hi, by any chance is there **a Donald Trump** there?  Might be **a Ronald Trump**.

Side note: The only truly archaic part of the joke is the use of "master", a title which is rarely used nowadays, and almost never with the possessive as "his/her/your/my master".  That would sound *medieval*, or possibly *mad scientist*.  Nowadays we would say something like "boss", "teacher", "professor", or "tutor", depending on the exact nature of the relationship.

Ironically, in some contexts (usually art-related), "maestro" *is* a valid title, even though it literally is Italian for "master".